Como visualizar únicamente el widget con el que trabajo
He empezado recientemente a trabajar con flutter viniendo de SwiftUI. Y en swiftUI el emulador va representando únicamente el contenido del archivo y no emula la aplicación completa. Aquí en flutter he estado todo ele ato reescribiendo el widget de "home:" para que muestre solamente con el que estoy trabajando. ¿Hay alguna maneras más eficiente de hacer que el emulador vaya mostrando los diferentes widget que estoy diseñando?
